# How to make width of th equal to each correspond th in another bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-table

I have two tables in bootstrap model..! I want to make the width of all `TH`s in first table equal to all correspond `TH`s in second table.
I am using jQuery `width()` method to achieve that but I am not being successful.

My code is here..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var countForThWidth = 1;
while (countForThWidth <= 11) {
var newWidth = $('.table-with-fixed-header > thead > tr > th:nth-child(' + countForThWidth + ')').width();
$('.fixed-thead-holder > table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(' + countForThWidth + ')').width(newWidth);
countForThWidth++;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content row">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">

       <div class="fixed-thead-holder">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Order Number</th>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Ordered</th>
                        <th>Received</th>
                        <th>Backordered</th>
                        <th>Unit Cost</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-with-fixed-header">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Ordered</th>
                    <th>Received</th>
                    <th>Backordered</th>
                    <th>Unit Cost</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td>Image here</td>
              <td>ICS-HS-16401810</td>
              <td>4248</td>
              <td>OVEN CLEANER, 4.1GAL, LIQUID</td>
              <td>CS</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>$400.00</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>$2000.00</td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the width of all `th` equal to each correspond  `th` in second table..!
Like this images:

[image]

Thank You ...!

Comment: try to add different id's for each table and use them in your code to know to where to get the newWidth. And remove the external source after <div class="table-responsive"> . Move before div

Comment: And how does your CSS look like? ... Note, to set fixed widths the table layout need to be fixed.

Comment: You don't need a separate table to achieve fixed headers - see [this](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu) for example.

Comment: @LGSon I am using bootstrap css..!

Comment: @Roamer Sorry to say but I have used that example but it is not being good idea for all devices and all breakpoints..!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 because my table contains large amount of data..!

Answer (score 2):

Try this but it's look strange. You have to set max-width not just for th but for td as well. And have to hide the extra text. And yes I've forgot was an error because the modal wasn't loaded (thanx @WizardCoder)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
var countForThWidth = 1;
while (countForThWidth <= 11) {
var newWidth = $('#second thead tr th:nth-child(' + countForThWidth + ')').outerWidth();
$('#first thead tr th:nth-child(' + countForThWidth + ')').css("min-width", newWidth);
/*$('#second tbody tr td:nth-child(' + countForThWidth + ')').css("max-width", newWidth);*/
countForThWidth++;
}
})
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="table-responsive">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content row">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">

       <div class="fixed-thead-holder">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="first">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Order Number</th>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Ordered</th>
                        <th>Received</th>
                        <th>Backordered</th>
                        <th>Unit Cost</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-with-fixed-header" id="second">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Ordered</th>
                    <th>Received</th>
                    <th>Backordered</th>
                    <th>Unit Cost</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td>Image here</td>
              <td>ICS-HS-16401810</td>
              <td>4248</td>
              <td>OVEN CLEANER, 4.1GAL, LIQUID</td>
              <td>CS</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>$400.00</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>$2000.00</td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed the white-space wrap. The question was how to set the width of TH from second table like in the first table. Or maybe I understood wrong. Ohh yes, my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your code was not able to get the th widths because the modal was hidden on load. I have put your code inside an `on` function that checks for when the modal shown event has been triggered. I have also set the table layout to fixed, because this is required for fixed width table cells.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    var countForThWidth = 1;
      while (countForThWidth <= 11) {
      var newWidth = $('.table-with-fixed-header > thead > tr > th:nth-child(' + countForThWidth + ')').outerWidth();
      $('.fixed-thead-holder > table > thead > tr > th:nth-child(' + countForThWidth + ')').outerWidth(newWidth);
      countForThWidth++;
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.fixed-thead-holder > table {
 table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content row">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">

       <div class="fixed-thead-holder">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Order Number</th>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Ordered</th>
                        <th>Received</th>
                        <th>Backordered</th>
                        <th>Unit Cost</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-with-fixed-header">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Ordered</th>
                    <th>Received</th>
                    <th>Backordered</th>
                    <th>Unit Cost</th>
                    <th>Brand</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td>Image here</td>
              <td>ICS-HS-16401810</td>
              <td>4248</td>
              <td>OVEN CLEANER, 4.1GAL, LIQUID</td>
              <td>CS</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>$400.00</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>$2000.00</td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```